# ComboBox.DropDownWidth property only takes effect upon second form showing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, imagelist

I have a simple `FixedToolWindow` form that has a `ComboBox`. I have set the `DropDownWidth` property to 53. I am also populating the `ComboBox` with images from an `ImageList`.

When I first open the form using `PreferencesForm.ShowDialog()`, the width of the drop down list is greater than 53 like below:

[image: Undesired DropDownWidth]

When I close the form and reopen using `PreferencesForm.ShowDialog()` this is the desired result I get until I restart debugging:

[image: Desired DropDownWidth]

Here is my PreferenceForm class:

```
public partial class PreferencesForm : Form
{
    private Form1 MainForm;
    public TabControl TabControl { get; set; }

    public PreferencesForm(Form1 mainForm)
    {
        MainForm = mainForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PreferencesForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = Preferences.ColorIndex;
    }

    private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        if (e.Index > -1 && imageList1.Images.Count >= e.Index)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.Index], new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
    }
}
```

Here is my Form1 class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PreferencesForm PreferencesForm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PreferencesForm = new PreferencesForm(this);
    }

    private void preferencesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PreferencesForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've been able to narrow the problem down to the direct cause. 
When I change ItemHeight in the ComboBox the problem occurs. 
When it is at default (15) this problem does not occur.

**Strangely, when I set the ItemHeight to any value (including 15!) the problem occurs.**

So when the ItemHeight appears bold in the properties page the issue described occurs but when I right click "reset" and the ItemHeight turns to a grey 15 there is no problem.
Can anyone else replicate this? 
The ComboBox has a draw mode of DrawOwnerVariable.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm just quite baffled!

Comment: Try to move the setting of the initial SelectedIndex in the Form_Shown event

Comment: I gave that a go but the result is just as it was before.

Comment: This doesn't reproduce the problem. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So I've recreated the project and the problem isn't replicated. I'll work on finding the cause of the problem now. OK I have found the direct cause of the issue. I have set Item height to 32 (the height of the images). This causes the problem to replicate.

Comment: I've got the solution! Make sure ItemHeight is grey in the properties menu (right click "reset"). Then in the Form_Shown method set ComboBox.ItemHeight = 32;

Comment: Usually the first benefit of trying to post MCVE is for you, because you find the solution yourself, or find the problem is because of a setting which you didn't mention in the post :)

Comment: Thank you, it was great advice. I'll use it for all future questions!